# pytorch - net.cuda() seems don't work

Tags: python, pytorch

I wrote a cnn module to do digit recognition using pytorch, then try to train the network with gpu but got following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 51, in <module>
    outputs = cnn(inputs)
  File "/home/daniel/anaconda3/envs/pytorch/lib/python3.5/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 357, in __call__
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/home/daniel/Code/kaggle-competitions/digit-recognizer/Net.py", line 40, in forward
    x = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv[i](x)))
  File "/home/daniel/anaconda3/envs/pytorch/lib/python3.5/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 357, in __call__
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/home/daniel/anaconda3/envs/pytorch/lib/python3.5/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/conv.py", line 282, in forward
    self.padding, self.dilation, self.groups)
  File "/home/daniel/anaconda3/envs/pytorch/lib/python3.5/site-packages/torch/nn/functional.py", line 90, in conv2d
    return f(input, weight, bias)
RuntimeError: Input type (CUDAFloatTensor) and weight type (CPUFloatTensor) should be the same
```

here is my [source code](https://github.com/team6612/kaggle-competitions/tree/master/digit-recognizer)

It seems that `cnn.cuda()` didn't work properly because I got the same error after removing it. But I have no idea how to fix it.

Comment: sorry for asking this stupid question but did you make double sure torch.cuda.is_available() returns True? Input might be getting cuda from somewhere else

Comment: Thanks for help and yes it does return True. I just try to print some text in both if-statements. They both printed but still got the error. What do you mean 'getting cuda from somewhere else'?

Comment: Forget about what I said about that, sorry I was thinking about something else. Off topic but len((1024,)) returns 1 not 2. I am not sure if that has to do anything with the cuda problem but I think it's against what you want to achieve. In Net.py  line 44, you might want to add a +1 there

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Daniel's answer to his own question seems to be correct. The problem is indeed that modules are not recognized if they are appended to a list. However, Pytorch also provides built-in solutions to this problem:
[nn.ModuleList](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/nn.html?highlight=sequential#torch.nn.ModuleList) and [nn.ModuleDict](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/nn.html?highlight=sequential#torch.nn.ModuleDict) are two container types that keep track of the added content and their parameters. 
Both have the same functionality as their Python equivalents, but the dictionary uses named arguments and can be used to keep track of for example task-specific layers.

A working example would be:

```
    self.conv = torch.nn.ModuleList()
    self.conv.append(nn.Conv2d(1, channels[0], kernel_sizes[0]))
    self.conv_img_size = math.floor((self.conv_img_size - (kernel_sizes[0]-1))/2)

    for i in range(1, self.conv_layer_size):
        self.conv.append(nn.Conv2d(channels[i-1], channels[i], kernel_sizes[i]))
        self.conv_img_size = math.floor((self.conv_img_size - (kernel_sizes[i]-1))/2)
        # Modules are automatically added to the model parameters
```

Comment: That's much more clear and I think it's better to use official container. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I solved it by myself. It's because I assigned the child modules in non-standard way, the submodules wasn't registered to the child module list of my module. The `module.parameter()` won't return parameters of these unregistered submodules. And `module.cuda()` only move the registered parameters to GPU.

By default, if you assign the child module is this way, the submodule will be registered automatically:

```
class Model(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Model, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(1, 20, 5)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(20, 20, 5)
```

However, I assigned the submodules by append them to a list:

```
class Cnn(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, channels, kernel_sizes, dense_layers, n_classes, img_size):
        super(Cnn, self).__init__()

        ...

        self.conv = []
        self.conv.append(nn.Conv2d(1, channels[0], kernel_sizes[0]))
        self.conv_img_size = math.floor((self.conv_img_size - (kernel_sizes[0]-1))/2)
        for i in range(1, self.conv_layer_size):
            self.conv.append(nn.Conv2d(channels[i-1], channels[i], kernel_sizes[i]))
            self.conv_img_size = math.floor((self.conv_img_size - (kernel_sizes[i]-1))/2)
```

I need to call `module.add_module` manually to register these submodules.

```
class Cnn(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, channels, kernel_sizes, dense_layers, n_classes, img_size):
        super(Cnn, self).__init__()

        ...

        self.conv = []
        self.conv.append(nn.Conv2d(1, channels[0], kernel_sizes[0]))
        self.conv_img_size = math.floor((self.conv_img_size - (kernel_sizes[0]-1))/2)
        self.add_module('Conv0', self.conv[0]) # Add modules manually
        for i in range(1, self.conv_layer_size):
            self.conv.append(nn.Conv2d(channels[i-1], channels[i], kernel_sizes[i]))
            self.conv_img_size = math.floor((self.conv_img_size - (kernel_sizes[i]-1))/2)
            self.add_module('Conv'+str(i), self.conv[i]) # Add modules manually
```

You can check the registered modules by print the module instance.

Before adding `module.add_module`:

```
>>> print(cnn)
Cnn(
  (pool): MaxPool2d(kernel_size=(2, 2), stride=(2, 2), dilation=(1, 1), ceil_mode=False)
  (output_layer): Linear(in_features=1024, out_features=10, bias=True)
)
```

After:

```
>>> print(cnn)
Cnn(
  (Conv0): Conv2d(1, 32, kernel_size=(5, 5), stride=(1, 1))
  (Conv1): Conv2d(32, 64, kernel_size=(5, 5), stride=(1, 1))
  (pool): MaxPool2d(kernel_size=(2, 2), stride=(2, 2), dilation=(1, 1), ceil_mode=False)
  (Dense0): Linear(in_features=1024, out_features=1024, bias=True)
  (output_layer): Linear(in_features=1024, out_features=10, bias=True)
)
```